# Can a base class know properties of the object implementing it

Tags: c#, inheritance, derived-class, base-class

I am implementing a Base object class to implement XmlSerializer.

```
class FN_ObjectBase
{
    public object FromXML(string xml)
    {
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof("ObjectA??"));

        var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml));

        var scriptItem = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

        return scriptItem;
    }
}

class ObjectA : FN_ObjectBase
{
    public object = new ObjectA.FromXML("serializedXML");
}
```

How can I correctly write the FromXML method to create any object based on the derived class?

Comment: I think you should just have FromXML be an abstract method - and then each derived class of FN_ObjectBase can implement their own version.

Comment: Inheritance isn't supposed to put the children's responsibilities in the parent class.  You can define a base behavior and override it in the child classes when the implementation is different.  So the answer to the question in the title is no.

Comment: @LeslieDavies If the only difference in implementation is the type the method is being invoked on there is no need to *not* have an implementation of the method in the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use a generic method:

```
public T FromXML<T>(string xml)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

    var reader = new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(xml));

    var scriptItem = serializer.Deserialize(reader);

    return (T)scriptItem;
}
```

Call it:

```
FromXML<ObjectA>("serialized xml")
```

OOP rule:
Never use derived types in a base type.

Comment: generics FTW in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an abstract method, and while the generic method implementation would work, it signals a slightly different (although probably better) intent to the caller.

All you need to do is pass `this.GetType()` to the `XMLSerializer` constructor in your base implementation.